# Is it possible to have a new list item created without automatically inheriting the parent list permissions?

Tags: inheritance

I have created a document set whereby each record can only be access by an individual so they can upload documents to that document set.  Problem is as each new document set is created, it inherits all of the root permissions so the list of 'limited access' users is growing, which then in turn makes it difficult to determine absolutely that the correct person/group has the correct permissions for that document set.

I would prefer to be able to just create a new document set, then just go and add the relevant permissions for it, rather then having to delete 800+ and going items on the permissions...

Any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to break the inheritance of your Library permission.

1. Go to your Library Setting
2. Permissions for this document library
3. Stop inheriting permissions
4. then set your default permissions

The next document set you will create will inherit the permission from your Library.

Regards,
Christophe

Answer (score 0):

y default, Document Sets inherit permissions from the library in which they are located. You can opt to specify unique permissions for a Document Set if you need to restrict or change who has access to the documents in an individual Document Set.

Managing unique permissions at the item-level or folder-level can be complicated and time-consuming. If most Document Sets will need to be accessible to similar groups, it may be easier to manage permissions at the library level.

To manage the permissions for a Document Set, you must have at least    the Design or Full Control permission level.

1. On the Welcome Page for the Document Set, click the Manage tab of
   the    Document Set ribbon, and then click Permissions.
2. Do one of the following:

   - To change the permission settings for the document library itself, click Manage Parent.
   - To stop inheriting permissions from the document library and create unique permissions for this Document Set individually, click Stop Inheriting Permissions.
   - To view the specific permissions an individual has, click Check Permissions, and then type the name of the user or group you want to check.
   - To inherit permissions from the parent document library (if the Document Set was previously configured to stop inheriting them) click Inherit Permissions.

Read more here: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/create-and-manage-document-sets-c71d5796-d559-48de-b1b3-42383bdd13ea#__toc355081704

http://sharepointmetadataandclassification.typepad.com/blog/2010/05/security-for-sharepoint-2010-document-sets.html